How to run gnus nnmail-split on sequentially chunked mbox files?
I have successfully run the script to split my unmanageably huge mbox file (21gb, causing my emacs to freeze when trying to deal with it) into 508 digestible chunks, named something like chunk_0508.txt. How do I sequentially feed them to emacs gnus to process them without repeating myself 508 times? Manually it would be something like changing my spool file to chunk_0001.txt, and then, when it finishes processing that one, move on to the next one. How can I automate this so that it upon finishing one, it handles eg chunk_0002.txt?

I got it. The solution needs to be in elisp because only gnus itself knows when it is finished with its thing. So, in proper emacs fashion (including dynamic scoping), here was the solution:
    (let ((gnus-interactive-exit nil)
        (files (directory-files "/var/spool/mail/" t "chunk.*"))
        (composing-files))
        (dolist (f files composing-files)
          (message (concat "Processing: " f))
          (setq composing-files (cons f composing-files))
          (let ((mail-sources `((file :path ,f))))
        (gnus)
        (gnus-group-exit)))
        (message (concat "processed all of " composing-files)))

